# How to eval() a string in a dictionary Python2.7

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame, eval

I have a dictionary:

```
key = {'K_z':'K_w'}
```

I want to get K_w as a value name instead of a string, I heard that the eval() function can convert strings to value names.

But when I type:

```
print(eval(key['K_z']))
```

I get 'K_z' instead of having the K_w value.

Can you help me ?

If it helps, I'm using it for pygame to let the player change the key bindings, specially with AZERTY and QWERTY differences...

Comment: What do you mean by "value name"? This sounds like a very wrong use of `eval()`.

Comment: Do you mean `K_w=something; key['K_z']==something`?

Comment: @dawg yes, as the pygame libraries functions recognises K_w but not 'K_w'

Comment: I guess you don't want `eval`, but you just really want to resolve `K_w` (or whatever name `key["K_z"]` indicates) from the `pygame.key` module. Assuming that you did `import pygame.key`, does `getattr(pygame.key, key["K_z"])` get you what you need?

Comment: @Rhymoid No, console says me: 'module' object has no attribute 'K_w'

Comment: Ah, sorry; I've never worked with Pygame before. How about `getattr(pygame, key["K_z"])`?

Comment: @Rhymoid Ok that is what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
key = {'K_z':'K_w'}
print(key['K_z'])
```

K_w

I don't think that `eval()` will help as it evaluates arguments. In pygame you could use `if key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_z]` do something.